# How to handle Rust's errors from Result as a return value instead of throwing an exception in JavaScript?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I'd like to write JavaScript like:

```js
var [greeting, err] = wasm.hello("world");
```

It appears that if I use the standard `Result` type, then I need to use a `try`/`catch`:

```js
try {
  greeting = wasm.hello()
}
catch(error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Rust code that generates the error:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn hello(name: &str) -> Result<String, JsValue> {
    if name == "" {
        return Err(JsValue::from("name required!"));
    }

    let greeting = format!("Hello {}!", name);

    Ok(greeting)
}
```

This is based on the example in [rust-parcel-template](https://github.com/rustwasm/rust-parcel-template). The full webapp with Rust + WASM + JS with the little example above is on [GitHub](https://github.com/ultrasaurus/hello-rust-parcel/blob/hello/js/index.js).

Comment: Using such a construct seems like a bad idea. In Rust, the type system will prevent you from accidentally using the success value in an error case and vice versa, but nothing provides that security in JavaScript. Returning a pair of values means you can trivially ignore the error, and in fact are almost *encouraged* to do so. It seems a better idea to use the language's natural error handling strategy.

Comment: well, I wanted to ask about best practices for error handling across the boundary of Rust / wasm / Javascript, but stackoverflow warned me against that.  The examples I've found so far don't seem to illustrate error handling.

Comment: Isn't `try` / `catch` the proper error handling strategy for JavaScript? Using a `Result` is certainly the correct one for Rust. I'd expect that the automatic conversion of a failed `Result` into an exception **is** the best practice. `var [greeting, err] = wasm.hello("world")` feels very Go-like, not idiomatic JS.

Comment: https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/types/result.html, I don't see any information about an alternative.

Comment: @Stargateur The wasm-bindgen guide [has a section on Supported Types](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/types/result.html): *Whenever `Ok(val)` is encountered it's converted to JS and handed off, and whenever `Err(error)` is encountered an exception is thrown in JS with `error`.*

Comment: At least for undefined and null, throwing an exception doesn't make sense because only a local exception handler could understand it. https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1734.